# Server Rack Relocation...Least Bumpy Option?

Tags: rack

So I have a floor-standing half rack on wheels. Something similar to this --> [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Portable-Server-Rack-Cabinet/dp/B006ZLV5HA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006ZLV5HA). It's loaded up with server equipment that was configured in a staging area of the office. Since the production wiring closet didn't have room to accommodate the new half rack.

Now the half rack is live and I've pulled the old equipment from the production wiring closet. So I need to move the half rack into there. The half rack weighs roughly 400 pounds. While it is on wheels, there are at least three spots where the flooring is uneven --- leading from the hard floor to the carpet tiles, leading from the carpet tiles back to hard flooring, and some recessed areas of the hard flooring. While just pulling out the rack contents one at a time might sound like an option, the heaviest component in there is a populated Dell MX7000, which alone weighs over 200 pounds.

Logistically what would be good options for smoothing out the surfaces? Since the unit is so heavy, pushing it over the transition points would be tough and the jostling isn't the best thing. A co-worker has suggested laying down Masonite. Anyone have any recommendations about something I can do to lessen the bumps in the road?

Comment: **A co-worker has suggested laying down Masonite** - Yes. Do that.

Comment: Only slight hitch is I believe the Masonite panels come 4 by 8 feet. Some key areas might be just under 4 feet wide, although certainly could see about cutting the panels to accommodate.

Comment: If you need to cut the panels to fit then cut the panels to fit. Or use something else that can smooth the transitions without you needing to lift or jostle the rack.